# Combining orElseThrows?

Tags: java, option-type

I have the following code and it works as expected:

```
Optional.ofNullable(testItem.getId())
                .map(testItemRepository::get)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new TestException(ReturnCode.UNKNOWN_ID))
                .orElseThrow(() -> new TestException(ReturnCode.UNKNOWN_ID));
```

I would like to know if there is a way to just have one orElseThrow-Part or do it less redundant ?

Comment: It's hard to tell because it's not clear what `testItemRepository::get` returns (does it return an `Option`?). Try using `flatMap` instead of `map` and remove the last `orElseThrow` line.

Comment: Yes it returns an optional. thx for the quick answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Optional#flatMap` method that flattens the Optional structure as long the call of the method `testItemRepositoryget` results in `Optional`.

```
 Optional.ofNullable(testItem.getId())
            .flatMap(testItemRepository::get)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new TestException(ReturnCode.UNKNOWN_ID));
```

I.e. from `Optional<Optional<MyObject>>` to `Optional<MyObect>`.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be the case that `testItemRepository::get` returns another `Optional<Something>`. In that case, you should not use `map`. Using `map` will get you a nested optional - `Optional<Optional<Something>>`, which as you have found out, is not nice to work with. `flatMap` is made for exactly this situation:

```
Optional.ofNullable(testItem.getId())
            .flatMap(testItemRepository::get)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new TestException(ReturnCode.UNKNOWN_ID));
```

`flatMap` turns an `Optional<A>` to an `Optional<B>`, given a `Function<A, Optional<B>>`.